# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo; java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity

Tenho um projeto de um chat socket funcionando em Swing e agora estou passando ele pro Android.

Estava tudo funcionando perfeitamente até que eu coloquei o código que faz a magia acontecer. O aplicativo fechava e eu não sabia porque já que tinha corrigido todos os erros do código em si.

Passei pelo debug e encontrei o tal erro dizendo que eu não podia instanciar nada antes do `onCreate()`. Como podem ver não há nada antes dele (visivelmente).
Perguntei para alguns professores e me disseram que o problema poderia ser no ciclo de vida da minha activity. Ainda não descobri o erro. Em tese o código está certo.

meu MainActivity.java:

```
package com.lucas.appchat;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.message = new ChatMessage();
        this.message.setAction(ChatMessage.Action.CONNECT);
        this.message.setName(nome);

        this.service = new ClienteService();
        this.socket = this.service.connect();

        new Thread(new ListenerSocket(this.socket)).start();

        this.service.send(message);
    }

    public void btnEnviar(View view) {
        btnEnviarActionPerformed();
    }

    public MessageViewHolder holder = new MessageViewHolder();
    public LayoutInflater messageInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    private Socket socket;
    private ChatMessage message;
    private ClienteService service;
    private ObjectOutputStream outputStream;
    public EditText txtAreaSend = findViewById(R.id.textBox);

    ListView listOnlines2;
    String[] array;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array);


    private class ListenerSocket implements Runnable {

        private ObjectInputStream input;

        public ListenerSocket(Socket socket) {
            try {
                this.input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ChatMessage message;
            try {
                while ((message = (ChatMessage) input.readObject()) != null) {
                    ChatMessage.Action action = message.getAction();

                    if (action.equals(ChatMessage.Action.CONNECT)) {
                        connected(message);
                    } else if (action.equals(ChatMessage.Action.DISCONNECT)) {
                        refreshOnlines(message);
                        disconnected();
                        socket.close();
                    } else if (action.equals(ChatMessage.Action.SEND_ONE)) {
                        receive(message);
                    } else if (action.equals(ChatMessage.Action.USERS_ONLINE)) {
                        refreshOnlines(message);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(MainActivity.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
        private void connect(ChatMessage message1) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    }

    private void connected(ChatMessage message) {
        if (message.getText().equals("NO")) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Coneão não realizada!\nTente novamente com um novo nome.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            message.setAction(ChatMessage.Action.DISCONNECT);
            this.service.send(message);
            disconnected();
            return;
        }
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Você está conectado no chat!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    private void disconnected() {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Você saiu do Chat!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void receive(ChatMessage message) {

        View convertView;

            convertView = messageInflater.inflate(R.layout.their_message, null);
            holder.avatar = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.messageBody = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_body);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

            holder.name.setText(message.getName());
            holder.messageBody.setText(message.getText());
            GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) holder.avatar.getBackground();
            drawable.setColor(Color.parseColor(message.getRandomColor()));


    }

    private void refreshOnlines(ChatMessage message) {
        System.out.println(message.getSetOnlines().toString());

        Set<String> names = message.getSetOnlines();

        names.remove(message.getName());

        array = (String[]) names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);



        listOnlines2.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }



    private void btnEnviarActionPerformed() {
        String text = this.txtAreaSend.getText().toString();
        String name = this.message.getName();

        this.message = new ChatMessage();


        this.message.setAction(ChatMessage.Action.SEND_ALL);


        if (!text.isEmpty()) {
            this.message.setName(name);
            this.message.setText(text);


            View convertView;

            convertView = messageInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_message, null);
            holder.messageBody = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_body);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
            holder.messageBody.setText(message.getText());


            this.service.send(this.message);
        }

        this.txtAreaSend.setText("");
    }

    private void btnSairActionPerformed() {
        ChatMessage message = new ChatMessage();
        message.setName(this.message.getName());
        message.setAction(ChatMessage.Action.DISCONNECT);
        this.service.send(message);
        disconnected();
    }


}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/messagesView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:divider="#fff" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Escrever..."
        android:inputType="text"
        android:paddingHorizontal="10dp"
        android:text="" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonSend"
        android:onClick="btnEnviar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Erros registrados no debug:

> ```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.stevenilson.appchat/com.stevenilson.appchat.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2038)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
>     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>     at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:4582)
>     at com.stevenilson.appchat.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:49)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
>     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2029)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241) 
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960) 
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038) 
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805) 
>     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

O erro ocorre porque você está tentando acessar componentes do Android antes de a Activity ser criada, ou seja, antes do método `onCreate()` ser chamado. Dois exemplos dessas chamadas *ilegais* estão em:

```
public EditText txtAreaSend = findViewById(R.id.textBox);
public LayoutInflater messageInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

Repare que essas variáveis estão sendo inicializadas no corpo da classe, quando na verdade, devem ser inicializadas após ou dentro do método `onCreate()`. Sendo assim, uma solução seria declarar essas variáveis no corpo da classe, mas só inicializá-las dentro do `onCreate()`ou em algum outro método;

**Exemplo**

No corpo da classe:

```
public EditText txtAreaSend;
public LayoutInflater messageInflater;
```

Dentro do método `onCreate()`ou algum outro método:

```
messageInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
txtAreaSend = findViewById(R.id.textBox);
```

**Extra**

Seria legal você dar uma olhada no [ciclo de vida das Activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities?hl=pt-br) pra ter uma ideia melhor sobre em que momento chamar determinados métodos e inicializar suas variáveis.

Comment: tentei colocar dentro do onCreat() o instanciamento de tudo (3 variaveis) continuou falhando. Criei um metodo e coloquei a instanciação das variaveis dentro dele e chamei ele no onCreat() o que também deu errado. Os erros agora são:

Comment: ' java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.stevenilson.appchat/com.stevenilson.appchat.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException' ' Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException'     acho que tem haver com o array de strings